Why does the MAUI Picker fire the OnSelectionChanged event twice, with the first event being my selection and the second being Index 0?
Using .NET8 with MAUI, on an Android 13 device, I am trying to implement a Picker with an ItemSource on a complex object.
However, may it be through using the SelectionIndexChanged event, binding SelectedIndex or binding SelectedItem, reacting to a new selection always fires the event twice with the first event being correct, i.e. the selection is indeed the one picked through the UI, and the second event always selects Index 0 of the ItemSource. This effectively renders the picker useless, or rather extremely loyal to the first element.
<!-- Preconfigured Device Configurations -->
<Picker
    ItemsSource="{Binding UserConfigs}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUserConfiguration}"
    Title="{Binding CurrentUserConfig.ConfigName}"
    TitleColor="{DynamicResource PrimaryTextColor}"
    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ConfigName}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding ConnectedDevice.Data.LockStatus, Converter={StaticResource LockStatusConverter}}"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Margin="10,0,0,0"
    FontSize="Small"
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>

The Picker is nested in a Grid, itself nested in a StackLayout, itself nested in a ContentPage using Shell navigation.
UserConfigs is an ObservableCollection<MyCustomObject>
SelectedUserConfiguration is a MyCustomObject
/// <summary>
/// Binded property of the currently selected user config the user whishes to set the XXXX to.
/// </summary>
public MyCustomObject SelectedUserConfiguration
{
     get => m_oSelectedUserConfig;
     set
     {
          m_oSelectedUserConfig = value;
          OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedUserConfiguration));
     }
}

With all of this, I was expecting the code would yield the same results as its Xamarin predecessor, and selecting an object from the Picker would have SelectedUserConfiguration update to the corresponding value.
It does, for a split second, then instantly reverts back to Index 0 selection. I'm really having a hard time figuring out why.

I can not reproduce the issue you are experiencing. Can you provide some more information?

I've been trying to reproduce my problem in a repo and I just can't.
As my main project is rather complex by now, I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong unrelated to the Picker itself.
Sorry for the rushed question, and thanks for the consideration.
